# can not get correct result by pytorch on my MacBook Pro M1

Tags: macos, pytorch, apple-m1, transformer-model, cs231n

I am learning Transformer_Captioning.ipynb of cs231n assignment3.
According to its guide, I need to run the cell which can test my MultiHeadAttention implementation, and I need to get the relative error should be less than e-3.
After I have finished my code, I got incorrect result:

```
self_attn_output error:  0.449382070034207
masked_self_attn_output error:  1.0
attn_output error:  1.0
```

I even copied other people's code on gtihub which can get correct result, and, I still the same output:

```
self_attn_output error:  0.449382070034207
masked_self_attn_output error:  1.0
attn_output error:  1.0
```

Is there anything else I missed?

My Class：

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
import math

class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    """
    A model layer which implements a simplified version of masked attention, as
    introduced by "Attention Is All You Need" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762).

    Usage:
      attn = MultiHeadAttention(embed_dim, num_heads=2)

      # self-attention
      data = torch.randn(batch_size, sequence_length, embed_dim)
      self_attn_output = attn(query=data, key=data, value=data)

      # attention using two inputs
      other_data = torch.randn(batch_size, sequence_length, embed_dim)
      attn_output = attn(query=data, key=other_data, value=other_data)
    """

    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads, dropout=0.1):
        """
        Construct a new MultiHeadAttention layer.

        Inputs:
         - embed_dim: Dimension of the token embedding
         - num_heads: Number of attention heads
         - dropout: Dropout probability
        """
        super().__init__()
        assert embed_dim % num_heads == 0

        # We will initialize these layers for you, since swapping the ordering
        # would affect the random number generation (and therefore your exact
        # outputs relative to the autograder). Note that the layers use a bias
        # term, but this isn't strictly necessary (and varies by
        # implementation).
        self.key = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim)
        self.query = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim)
        self.value = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim)
        self.proj = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim)

        self.attn_drop = nn.Dropout(dropout)

        self.n_head = num_heads
        self.emd_dim = embed_dim
        self.head_dim = self.emd_dim // self.n_head

    def forward(self, query, key, value, attn_mask=None):
        """
        Calculate the masked attention output for the provided data, computing
        all attention heads in parallel.

        In the shape definitions below, N is the batch size, S is the source
        sequence length, T is the target sequence length, and E is the embedding
        dimension.

        Inputs:
        - query: Input data to be used as the query, of shape (N, S, E)
        - key: Input data to be used as the key, of shape (N, T, E)
        - value: Input data to be used as the value, of shape (N, T, E)
        - attn_mask: Array of shape (S, T) where mask[i,j] == 0 indicates token
          i in the source should not influence token j in the target.

        Returns:
        - output: Tensor of shape (N, S, E) giving the weighted combination of
          data in value according to the attention weights calculated using key
          and query.
        """
        N, S, E = query.shape
        N, T, E = value.shape
        # Create a placeholder, to be overwritten by your code below.
        output = torch.empty((N, S, E))
        ############################################################################
        # TODO: Implement multiheaded attention using the equations given in       #
        # Transformer_Captioning.ipynb.                                            #
        # A few hints:                                                             #
        #  1) You'll want to split your shape from (N, T, E) into (N, T, H, E/H),  #
        #     where H is the number of heads.                                      #
        #  2) The function torch.matmul allows you to do a batched matrix multiply.#
        #     For example, you can do (N, H, T, E/H) by (N, H, E/H, T) to yield a  #
        #     shape (N, H, T, T). For more examples, see                           #
        #     https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html          #
        #  3) For applying attn_mask, think how the scores should be modified to   #
        #     prevent a value from influencing output. Specifically, the PyTorch   #
        #     function masked_fill may come in handy.                              #
        ############################################################################
        # *****START OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****

        H = self.n_head

        # Compute key, query and value matrices from sequences
        K = self.key(key).view(N, T, H, E // H).moveaxis(1, 2)
        Q = self.query(query).view(N, S, H, E // H).moveaxis(1, 2)
        V = self.value(value).view(N, T, H, E // H).moveaxis(1, 2)

        Y = Q @ K.transpose(2, 3) / math.sqrt(self.head_dim)

        if attn_mask is not None:
            Y = Y.masked_fill(attn_mask == 0, float("-inf"))

        Y = self.attn_drop(F.softmax(Y, dim=-1)) @ V
        output = self.proj(Y.moveaxis(1, 2).reshape(N, S, E))

        # *****END OF YOUR CODE (DO NOT DELETE/MODIFY THIS LINE)*****
        ############################################################################
        #                             END OF YOUR CODE                             #
        ############################################################################
        return output
```

My test code:

```
import torch
if torch.backends.mps.is_available():
    mps_device = torch.device("mps")
    x = torch.ones(1, device=mps_device)
    print (x)
else:
    print ("MPS device not found.")

torch.manual_seed(231)

# Choose dimensions such that they are all unique for easier debugging:
# Specifically, the following values correspond to N=1, H=2, T=3, E//H=4, and E=8.
batch_size = 1
sequence_length = 3
embed_dim = 8
attn = MultiHeadAttention(embed_dim, num_heads=2)

# Self-attention.
data = torch.randn(batch_size, sequence_length, embed_dim)
self_attn_output = attn(query=data, key=data, value=data)

# Masked self-attention.
mask = torch.randn(sequence_length, sequence_length) < 0.5
masked_self_attn_output = attn(query=data, key=data, value=data, attn_mask=mask)

# Attention using two inputs.
other_data = torch.randn(batch_size, sequence_length, embed_dim)
attn_output = attn(query=data, key=other_data, value=other_data)

expected_self_attn_output = np.asarray([[
[-0.2494,  0.1396,  0.4323, -0.2411, -0.1547,  0.2329, -0.1936,
          -0.1444],
         [-0.1997,  0.1746,  0.7377, -0.3549, -0.2657,  0.2693, -0.2541,
          -0.2476],
         [-0.0625,  0.1503,  0.7572, -0.3974, -0.1681,  0.2168, -0.2478,
          -0.3038]]])

expected_masked_self_attn_output = np.asarray([[
[-0.1347,  0.1934,  0.8628, -0.4903, -0.2614,  0.2798, -0.2586,
          -0.3019],
         [-0.1013,  0.3111,  0.5783, -0.3248, -0.3842,  0.1482, -0.3628,
          -0.1496],
         [-0.2071,  0.1669,  0.7097, -0.3152, -0.3136,  0.2520, -0.2774,
          -0.2208]]])

expected_attn_output = np.asarray([[
[-0.1980,  0.4083,  0.1968, -0.3477,  0.0321,  0.4258, -0.8972,
          -0.2744],
         [-0.1603,  0.4155,  0.2295, -0.3485, -0.0341,  0.3929, -0.8248,
          -0.2767],
         [-0.0908,  0.4113,  0.3017, -0.3539, -0.1020,  0.3784, -0.7189,
          -0.2912]]])

print('self_attn_output error: ', rel_error(expected_self_attn_output, self_attn_output.detach().numpy()))
print('masked_self_attn_output error: ', rel_error(expected_masked_self_attn_output, masked_self_attn_output.detach().numpy()))
print('attn_output error: ', rel_error(expected_attn_output, attn_output.detach().numpy()))
```

My configuration:
MacBook Pro M1、Python 3.8.12、conda 4.11.0、torch 2.1.0.dev20230415、macOS Monterey Version 12.5

Answer (score -1):

I also met this question.

You can code this in Colab , and you will find your answer is right.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35440759)

Comment: Based on the question, this response isn't helpful. Please create a new one specifically for the question at hand.